# Can I send an array of objects with Jersey (and MOXy)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jaxb, jersey, moxy

I want to send an array of `Match` to a server. This is Match.java:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Match {
public enum State {
    Updated, Synced
};

@XmlElement
public int matchId;

@XmlElement
public int timeFrom;

@XmlElement
public int timeTo;

@XmlElement
public MatchConfig config; // can be null

public State state;

public Match() {
}
}
```

However when I send an array it tells me this:

WARNING: /api/match
java.lang.ClassCastException: test.rest.Match cannot be cast to javax.xml.bi
nd.JAXBElement

Why does this happen?

My Servlet method looks like this

```
@POST
@Path(MATCH_PATH)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Match[] syncMatches(Match[] matches) {
    System.out.println("received matches!");
    return new Match[]{new Match()};
}
```

Btw, returning an array from the server to the client Does work, and also sending a single Match object to the server works.
Typical server json output is: `[{"matchId":12,"timeFrom":23,"timeTo":0}]`.
And what my client sends looks like this: `[{"matchId":-1,"timeTo":-1,"timeFrom":265}]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that existed in MOXy's `MOXyJsonProvider` class that was fixed in EclipseLink 2.5.1.

**Link to Resolved Issue**

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/413760

**Link to Download EclipseLink**

- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/

Comment: I don't use EclipseLink, but I do have the same stacktrace as in the first link. I checked all my other dependencies though, and everything seems to be up to date. (Jersey 2.10.1, Google App Engine Sdk 1.9.6 and javax servlet-api 2.5)

Comment: @user717572 - MOXy is a component of EclipseLink.